# ¿Cuándo uso "el" o "la" antes del nombre de una persona?

Tags: artículos, nombres-propios, persona-gramatical

¿Cuándo utilizo "la" o "el" antes del nombre de una persona? ¿Será cuando me refiera a ellos como "señor" o "señora / señorita" y no cuando les hablo?

Comment: En el apartado 4 de esta entrada sobre el artículo "el" del Diccionario panhispánico de dudas creo que responden a tu pregunta: https://www.rae.es/dpd/el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí. Cuando le hablas a una persona debes omitir los pronombres "el" o "la".
Ejemplos:

> Disculpe señor, ¿Dónde está el baño?

También puedes omitir "señor":

> Disculpe, ¿Dónde está el baño?

La palabra señor se usa cuando hablas de una persona desconocida:

> Ese señor de allí parece triste
>
> That man over there seems sad

> ¿Tu conoces a ese señor? Jamás le había visto.
>
> Do you know that man? I've never seen him before.

Los pronombres se usan cuando ya conoces a esa persona pero no dices su nombre.

> Juan es mi amigo. Él siempre me hace reír.
>
> Juan is my friend. He always makes me laugh.

Comment: ‘Jamás **lo** había visto’?